# What is the meaning of "It feels opaque to me"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

While trying to resolve a problem, there were several proposed solutions. Refering to one of these solution, someone said:

> It feels opaque to me

I know this person didn't agree with that solution but what does it precisely means?

**Update:**

I know the meaning of the word "Opaque" but I couldn't understand how a "solution" could have been "opaque"

Comment: Welcome to ELL! We expect people to do a little research before asking questions. In this case, you could look up  opaque in a good dictionary like this one http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/opaque, and maybe check out definition 1.1... If you still don't get it, you can write a question and provide details of your research (with links) so that we can see exactly what you don't understand.

Comment: I would more usually expect **opaque** to refer to a problem or the **explanation** of a solution rather than the solution itself. How confident are you that you understood to what opaque was being applied?

Comment: Consider "opaque" as the opposite of "clear".  The solution was either so confusing as to be completely without meaning, or it completely hid important information.

Comment: @MikeKozar's explanation seems perfectly clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opaque is most commonly used to refer to the lack of transparency of an object. For example, most objects are opaque with glass, water, some plastics being notable exceptions.

Another definition stems from the "no transparency" idea, but with a different definition of transparency. In this case, an opaque proposal is hard to understand. The person probably didn't like the solution because he couldn't understand it. If asked, he would probably list reasons such as 1) Confusing, 2) Not well thought out, 3) Convoluted, 4) Lacking in details or implementation, or 5) Hand waving word salad.

If confused about a word, A google search of "define [confusingWord]" will do wonders.

Comment: It was a complex solution for an easy problem but it could have been useful for solving also other different problems. I assume that he was trying to say that it was unnecessarily complex (and maybe confused). Thanks for your answer.